# Prevent window.WebSocket replacement

Tags: javascript

How can I prevent something like this

```
var realSocket = window.WebSocket;

class WebSocket {
    constructor(src) {
        console.log("binded...");

        this.ws = new realSocket(src);
        this.fakeMsgCb = () => {};
        this.ws.onmessage = (data) => this.msg(data);
    }

    set onopen(cb) {
        this.ws.onopen = cb;
    }

    set onclose(cb) {
        this.ws.onclose = cb;
    }

    msg(data) {
        console.log("incoming ->", data);
        this.fakeMsgCb(data);
    }

    send(data) {
        console.log("outgoing ->", data);
        this.ws.send(data);
    } 

    set onerror(cb) {
        this.ws.onerror = cb;
    }

    set onerror(cb) {
        this.ws.onerror = cb;
    }

    set onmessage(cb) {
        this.fakeMsgCb = cb;
    }

    get readyState() {
        return this.ws.readyState;
    }
}

window.WebSocket = WebSocket;
```

that can be pasted in the console or in a browser userscript and then they can easily log the data? Don't worry, I know that I mustn't trust the client and that's not to hide any security issue or anything else but I just want to make it a little harder to read Incoming & Outgoing data

Comment: A user can log web socket data even more easily with the browser’s developer tools. Don’t bother.

Comment: @Ryan all my data is Binary so no they can't https://image.prntscr.com/image/YXS5jsW6SXyICpH4ahA1BQ.png

Comment: assure your using https to connect to your clients then websockets will correspondingly connect using wss instead of simply a ws connection

Comment: @ScottStensland this doesn't prevent from logging and sending fake data with the code above

Comment: RFC6455 specifies that wss runs secure ... the data is sent encrypted ... only TLS cert holders can decrypt

Comment: @ScottStensland well just tried with the code above on some random website using HTTPS + WSS: https://image.prntscr.com/image/23HT8V-hRFmAEPmSUVOn0w.png and it still works...

Comment: this **replaces** the window WebSocket class

Comment: @ScottStensland it even works here on SO

Comment: with https + wss the payload is encrypted so yes they can log it however cannot decrypt

Comment: @ScottStensland please see the screenshot above... I **replace** the window.WebSocket class with a custom one which logs everything and can even send data... You can even try it yourself, you just need to past it to your DevTools console before the page loads.

Comment: @JeePing: Can’t you just click on a binary frame to read it? Look, there’s really no point in doing this. Someone can use the script debugger to insert a modified `WebSocket` into any scope if they wanted to use this approach rather than the dev tools anyway.